# Integration of complicated functions

Tags: calculus

Can we integrate $$\frac{1}{(\sec(x)+\tan(x))^m}$$ using elementary methods where $m$ is any real number

Comment: Do you want a closed form or just a way to integrate this?

Comment: Just a way to integrate

Comment: What restrictions, if any, do you want placed on $m$ --- positive integer, integer, rational number, ruler-and-compass constructible, expressible using radicals, algebraic, . . . ?

Comment: $m$ is any real number

Comment: Mathematica will spit out answers for any natural number value of m, but they don't appear to follow any sort of pattern. Mathematica returns the integral unevaluated when m is a decimal